# Disable auto formatting of period in SMS?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sms, samsung-galaxy-ace

When I type a domain like `example.com`, Android automatically formats it like this `example. Com`

Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to settings->Language and input

figure out which keyboard is active and look for the settings page for that keyboard.

Look for settings like: "predictive text", "auto punctuation", and "auto capatilize" If you have any of those settings ensure that they are turned off. Once you've done that test again.

If you wish to use some of these features it may be worth it to try flipping them on one by one and figuring out which is the actual culprit that is breaking your links.

Comment: I tried them none works although I do not have an "auto punctuation" option in my Froyo.

Comment: are you using the samsung keyboard or the stock system keyboard?

Comment: Well, there is no other keyboard than Samsung, it's the stock. I am using 3x4 keypad format.